# Liferay transactional method

Tags: java, transactions, liferay

I want to call method filterFindByG_U from DLFileEntryUtil. The problem is, that the method in which I call filterFindBy must be transactional. But I dont know how to do this. I tried to write an annotation @Transactional before the method declaration but this didn't help. Can someone please give me some idea how to do this in Liferay 6.2? The method that should be transactional is:

```
public List<DLFileEntry> filterEntriesPermissions(User user) {
    List<DLFileEntry> filtered = new ArrayList<DLFileEntry>();

    try {
        filtered = DLFileEntryUtil.filterFindByG_U(user.getGroupId(), user.getUserId());
    } catch (SystemException | PortalException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return filtered;
}
```

I will be thankful for some help and explanation.

Comment: why getter should be transactional?

Comment: well basically I want to obtain all documents from DB with VIEW premission in one method which can be used more than once

Comment: how is this related to transactions?

Comment: filterFindByG_U from documentation - Filters by the user's permissions and finds all the d l file entries where groupId = ? and userId = ?. but when I call this method I get this exception... No Hibernate Session bound to thread, and configuration does not allow creation of non-transactional one here

Comment: so, your problem because session cannot be created in this thread, not because you "must" use transactional method

Comment: im kinda confused, any useful idea how to handle this please ?

Comment: Post the exception here. So that we can help you out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this method:

```
DLFileEntryLocalServiceUtil.getGroupFileEntries(user.getGroupId(), user.getUserId(), QueryUtil.ALL_POS, QueryUtil.ALL_POS);
```